# Free library to generate simple bar graphs from database queries, within an ASP.net MVC web app

Tags: gratis, web-development, c#, charts, asp.net

In the spirit of this question [Suggest a free or open source charting or graphing tool for asp.net C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4186243/suggest-a-free-or-open-source-charting-or-graphing-tool-for-asp-net-c-sharp) on Stack Overflow.

I'm looking for a free tool to create charts for an ASP.net MVC web app, that takes data from database queries to form simple bar graphs e.g. number (int) per month and line graphs.

An example, but style is open to change, these are being totally replaced.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Essential Chart for ASP.NET MVC](http://mvc.syncfusion.com/demos/web/chart/default) supports multiple chart types including Bar charts and area charts.

[image: Chart types supported by Essential Chart]
[image: Chart types supported by Essential Chart]

The whole product is available for free through the [community license](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense) if you qualify (less than 1 million USD in revenue).

I work for Syncfusion.